# Why doesn't my image in html for slider work?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website for our project and I'm planning to use the infinite autoplay slider for "Our Team" and the image are not working. The only images that work are the icons and they're in png. The images that I use are also in png, so I don't really know why my images doesn't work. Although the slider is working, only the images doesn't show, why is like that?

This is my code for the html

```
<!-- Our Team -->
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide-track">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/black.jpg" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/chie.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is my code for css

```
/* Animation */
@keyframes scroll {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7))}
}


/* Styling */
.slider {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px; 
  padding-left: 5px;
}
    
.slider::before,
    .slider::after {
        content: "";
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .slider::after {
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        transform: rotateZ(180deg);
    }

    .slider::before {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    
    .slide-track {
        animation: scroll linear infinite;
    animation-duration: 40s;
        display: flex;
        width: calc(250px * 14);
    }
    
    .slide {
        height: 100px;
        width: 250px;  
   
    }

  img{
    height: 200px;
  }
```

I tried to use jpg but it's still the same, so I don't really know what to do, any tips -or could you please tell me why? However, the

Comment: hi, your code is correct. Check network tab in chrome-devtools. 
if you have problem with image you have to check image URI.

Comment: Does it work locally? Are the icons stored in the same place as the photos?

Comment: Hi, yes, the photos are stored in the same place as the icons.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to change the 100% { transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7))} to this 100% { transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 5))} and change the height on to the slide to 200px because the normal height put 200px and in the slider only 100px

Comment: Hi, I tried this and the outline of the images only got smaller. However, the images aren't still showing, only the icons which are in png. :<

Comment: ok i found the problem add 
.slide-track { 
display: flex;
animation: scroll linear infinite;
animation-duration: (set the time you want in seconds);
width: calc(250 * 5);
}
This code enable the display to be in animation in row, making and adding the animation scroll linear infinite make the animatino works as you desire a tested in my laptop only with another images and worked. if you have any more question i will be happy to answer :)